# ignore Python SyntaxError coming from `PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning`?

Tags: python, warnings, deprecation-warning

I'm using `PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning"` to raise exceptions on warnings, but I want to ignore certain such exceptions, which is normally fine. When the exception that results is `SyntaxError`, I would sometimes like to ignore that but don't know how.

Detailed example:

```
# has_deprecated_syntax.py
"""this becomes invalid: \* """
```

Then:

```
`$PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning" python3.6 -c "import     has_deprecated_syntax"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davidchudzicki/temp/so/has_deprecated_syntax.py", line 1
    """this becomes invalid: \* """
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence \*
```

These attempts to ignore it both got me the same failure:

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning,default::Warning:has_deprecated_syntax" python3.6 -c "import has_deprecated_syntax"
```

and

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning,default::SyntaxError" python3.6 -c "import has_deprecated_syntax"
```

For reference, here's what makes me think this is the correct environment setting in general for ignoring warnings from particular modules:

With:

```
# has_warning.py
import warnings
warnings.warn("hi")
```

... I get:

```
$PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning" python -c "import has_warning"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "has_warning.py", line 3, in <module>
    warnings.warn("hi")
UserWarning: hi
```

...which I can ignore with:

```
$PYTHONWARNINGS="error::Warning,default::Warning:has_warning" python -c 
"import has_warning"
has_warning.py:3: UserWarning: hi
  warnings.warn("hi")
```

But it doesn't work for SyntaxError. Is there any way to ignore those from particular modules?

(Note: I've constructed a small example for this question, but the real reason I care is that I want to fail on warnings in continuous integration for package I help with, but I get the `SyntaxError` from one of our dependencies when I do this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore SyntaxError.  It's not a warning, it's an error.

Comment: I get that you can't normally ignore syntax errors, but this one is only coming because warnings-as-errors is turned on. It sounds like what I want is impossible, but I don't think it's unreasonable to hope for an ability to tell the interpreter not to turn this warning into an error in this particular module (but still turn other warnings into errors).

Comment: Hmm - "[the warning] is already replaced with SyntaxError if the warning is raised as error" (https://bugs.python.org/issue32912#msg312575). That's consistent with what I'm seeing, but still doesn't explain why it can't be ignored.